# search by meta field in the regular WordPress admin panel search

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, search

I want to expand the Wordpress admin panel search using this code.

```
function add_search_query_meta( $query )
{
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_search )
        return;

    $s = get_search_query();

    $query->set( 'meta_query', [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'meta_key'     => '_company_inn',
            'value'   => $s,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        [
            'meta_key'     => '_company_phone',
            'value'   => $s,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
    ] );

    $query->set( 'post_type', 'company' );
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_search_query_meta' );

function modify_where_search_request( $where )
{
    if ( is_admin() || ! is_main_query() || ! is_search() )
        return $where;

    global $wpdb;

    $s = get_search_query();

    $where = preg_replace(
        [
            "~ OR \({$wpdb->posts}.post_[^\s]+ (LIKE '(?:%|{[^}]+}){$s}(?:%|{[^}]+})')\)~i", // убираем поиск по контенту и цитате
            "~AND\s+([\s(]+{$wpdb->wp_pn_companymeta}.meta_key)~i" // меняем AND условие мета-запроса на OR
        ],
        [
            '',
            'OR $1'
        ],
        $where
    );

    return $where;
}
add_action( 'posts_where_request', 'modify_where_search_request' );
```

Database structure:

[image]

Here are the keys I'm trying to access and get the value of:
[image]

I don't understand how to get these values through a standard search, help please..

[Here is the link to the plugin](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/PC99HGoq9tku8A)

Answer (score 0):

For regular admin panel search you should include "`is_admin()`" to be `true`.
For checking for specific post type you should check from `$query->get("post_type")`

Can you try to use this code

```
 add_action("pre_get_posts", function ($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_admin() && in_array($query->get('post_type'), array('company'))) {
        $s = get_search_query();
        $meta_query = [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'meta_key'     => '_company_inn',
                'value'   => $s,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ],
            [
                'meta_key'     => '_company_phone',
                'value'   => $s,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ],
        ];
        $query->set("s", $s);
        $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query);
    }

    return $query;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, but it didn't work for me :( After inserting this code, the Title search disappears